# Homework revisited

Tags: discussion, homework

This is an old topic but I see there is an influx of new questions on SE which would be resolved by a bit of googling and some thought. Presumably this is due to the new academic year up in the northern hemisphere.

Would a dedicated site to migrate homework questions to be a useful solution? It would also give lecturers/teachers a place to find who has been getting their homework done for them without having to trawl the internet

Comment: [This proposed site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44531/stack-overflow-homework) is similar, but is already closed.

Comment: It's in a good spirit , but SO already takes care of it

Comment: I like area51. You could possibly get your Computer Science qualification without opening a text book with just SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid this wouldn't be feasible. It just isn't StackOverflow's responsibility to control students. We *are not* their professors.

But we are good at catching "0-effort" questions. Users are naturally disinclined by copypasta homework queries.

But homework questions are *still* effort. Though tiny effort.. I think it's OK generally, to allow newbies to get "roughed up" here and maybe stay on to be good SO members( i.e., they ask a "gimme" HW question, it gets downvoted and closed, maybe they revisit with better strategy).

Comment: I'd disagree with "homework questions are still effort", unless you're counting "avoid learning anything", "cheating for a grade I don't deserve", or "wasting space that could be given to someone who actually wants to learn" as effort. I don't. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite The origin of the question as homework should not necessarily mean that no effort was shown. If someone provides what he has tried and where specifically he ran into a problem why shouldn't this be a valid question. (I agree that this is a rare case)

Comment: @bummi: That would be the rare exception. The vast majority of the homework questions I see are "Here's my requirement. <Copy/pasted verbiage from assignment>. Please help.". There was an excellent example last evening, but it was deleted shortly after it was posted, so I can't find a link to it. It gave a (relatively simple) two phrase requirement for recursion with an array, and said "I have no imagination about this. Can someone do it for me?" or something along those lines. The entire question was three lines of text and a one line code snippet with mismatching var names.